# GRAILS 2.5.0 unresolved dependency-report error

Tags: grails

when I run grails -version in command line it clearly shows version number. But whenever i try to run the app it shows the following error. how can i solve this?

[image]

Comment: Please give us a little example of your code, and copy-paste the error you obtain (no images)

Comment: No one can answer to your question please update question with some details in written as **stackoverflow** work with words not links.

Answer (score 0):

In upgrading from Grails 2.1 to 2.4.4 I found I had that same issue. The resolution was to explicitly set:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven"
```

in BuildConfig.groovy. Then I was able to move on to the next issue in the upgrade ... ;-)

**Try this not sure is that your issue or not**